# Get data from a ViewController via another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I got an App, where I have three `ViewControllers` with a `tableView`. They all are hierarchical, clubs -> members -> transactions. In the `memberVC`, there are all members from a club with their name and saldo displayed. The saldo there is calculated from the start amount and the amount of all transactions. Now I want to display at the clubs, the saldo of the whole club, calculated by the start amount of all members and the amount of all transactions from the members in the club. I tried it, but my solution throws this error at the `(member?.transactions)!` part:

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`.

This is my solution:

```
  var transcount = 0.0
        for trans in (member?.transactions)!{
            transcount = trans.money + transcount
       }

        var countmember = 0.0
        for membs in (club.members)! {
            countmember = membs.saldo + countmember
        }
```

[image: This is my Core-Data model]

That's how members are created:

```swift
  let member = Member(name: nameTextField.text ?? "", saldo: Double(saldoTextField.text!) ?? 0.0, surname: firstnameTextField.text ?? "")

        do{
            try member?.managedObjectContext?.save()
        } catch {
            print("Could not save member")
        }
        let name = nameTextField?.text
        let surname = firstnameTextField?.text
        let saldoText = saldoTextField?.text ?? ""
        let saldo = Double(saldoText) ?? 0.0

        if let member = Member(name: name, saldo: saldo, surname: surname) {
          club?.addToRawMembers(member)

            do {
                try member.managedObjectContext?.save()

                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            } catch {
                print ("Member couldn't be created")
           }
        }
    }
```

This is how transactions are created:

```swift
   let transaction = Trancsaction(money: Double(moneyTextField.text!) ?? 0.0, date: datePicker.date , reason: reasonTextField.text ?? "")
        do{
            try transaction?.managedObjectContext?.save()

        } catch{
            print("Could not save transaction")
        }

        let reason = reasonTextField?.text
        let moneyText = moneyTextField?.text ?? ""
        let money = Double(moneyText) ?? 0.00
        let date = datePicker?.date

        if let transaction = Trancsaction(money: money, date: date, reason: reason)   {
           member?.addToRawTransactions(transaction)

            do{
                try transaction.managedObjectContext?.save()

                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            } catch{
                print("Transaction could not be created")
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: First of all, for your own sanity, make sure to not force unwrap your variables, since it will be much easier for you to debug you code if you know weather a member actually exists or not. Which is probably the case for your error right now.
-
Secondly, make sure that your data model have all the details it need when you enter the first view controller, since I assume that you do not want to go through all three pages and then go back to display the calculated values for transaction?

Comment: @lindanordstrom What do you mean? Do I have to create a new Core Data model?

Comment: @lindanordstrom To the part with the force unwrap. Thank you for the hint, I am new in programming, so I appreciate every kind of help. I did this because xCode suggested this.

Comment: Well, correct me if I am wrong, but as far as I understand you have three pages of your app, and on the second and third page you do various calculations, right? 
That means, when you start the app first the first time and enter the first page, none of the calculations you want has happened yet, because you do them on the second and third page?

So what I mean is to make sure that everything is calculated for each club, member and transaction on app launch, and then you can populate the UI with correct data on each screen when you enter them. BUT I might not understand your question correct

Comment: Yeah I think you understood it right. On the second page there is a `tableView`with all members of a club. There is a cell with a label with the name and a detail label where the count of all transactions (from the third page) is plus the start amount of the member. This calculation works. Now I want to add the sum of all those detail label for a club, to the detail label of the cell from the club.

Answer (score 0):

You’re force-unwrapping a optional without a good reason—never do this. It could well happen that `member` or `transactions` is `nil`. Therefore, turn your code into safe code using this pattern:

```
var transcount = 0.0
if let transactions = member?.transactions {
    for trans in transactions {
        transcount = trans.money + transcount
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this. Now there is no error anymore, but the code still doesn't work like I want. There are just the start amounts of the members, but the transactions form the whole club aren't there.

Comment: Please add more code so we can see how you fill your members and transactions data structures. Currently they seem to be `nil`.

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: You’d not happen to have declared `Member` as a `struct`?

Comment: No I did not declare it as a `struct`

Comment: I’m asking because your code for initialising a new object looks funny. This is what the `init` function for a `NSManagedObject` looks like: `init(context:)`. I. e. this is what I’d expect to see in your code: `let member = Member(context: managedObjectContext)`. This way the object would be registered in the context and hence be saved upon calling `save()`. In your case, I believe your context simply doesn’t have any objects registered. You can verify this theory using the `hasChanges` property of your `NSManagedObjectContext` instance.

Comment: I have this code from a tutorial. This Is my first project so I don't really understand most things. My actual app works. But now I want, that the user can access the members of a club in a transaction and select them, to add a transaction to multiple members.